# How to retrieve all the keys of a given in Java HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

This is my program in Java.

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld
    {
  public static void main(String []args)
         {
            HashMap hm=new HashMap();
            hm.put("ansh",1);
            hm.put("ansh2",2);
            hm.put("ansh3",3);
            hm.put("ansh4",1);
            hm.put("ansh5",1);


         }
    }
```

Now I want to retrieve all the keys which give value 1?? How do we do this without iterating over the entire HashMap?

Comment: You can't. But you could maintain two maps - a second one for the reverse lookup

Comment: Think of implementing against the interface (Map) and prevent raw types.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution would be using a bidirectionel map like : http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap or https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html

Comment: No because if you use a `BiMap`, your values have to be unique. This is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Without iterating the `map`, this is not possible. I suspect you rather want to do this without having to iterate over the map yourself. If you want some readymade thing, that does the task for you, you should consider using `Guava` library. You can make use of [`Multimap`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) here.

```
Multimap<String, Integer> multiMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
multiMap.put("ansh",1);
multiMap.put("ansh2",2);
multiMap.put("ansh3",3);
multiMap.put("ansh4",1);
multiMap.put("ansh5",1);
```

This is similar to how you create a `Map`. Now coming to your question. You want all the keys, for a particular value `1`. In that case, you can create an inverse of this multimap. That will get you a `Multimap<Integer, String>`. And then you can get the value for key `1`:

```
Multimap<Integer, String> map = 
        Multimaps.invertFrom(multiMap, 
                             ArrayListMultimap.<Integer, String>create());

System.out.println(map.get(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reverse-lookup map is a `Map<Integer,List<String>>`. Once created, finding all strings with a given int-value is easy.

```
import  java.util.Arrays;
import  java.util.Iterator;
import  java.util.Set;
import  java.util.ArrayList;
import  java.util.HashMap;
import  java.util.List;

/**
   <P>{@code java MapAndReverseMapXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class MapAndReverseMapXmpl  {
   public static void main(String []args)  {
      HashMap<String,Integer> hmS2I = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
      HashMap<Integer,List<String>> hmI2S = new HashMap<Integer,List<String>>();

      addItem(hmS2I, hmI2S, "ansh",1);
      addItem(hmS2I, hmI2S, "ansh2",2);
      addItem(hmS2I, hmI2S, "ansh3",3);
      addItem(hmS2I, hmI2S, "ansh4",1);
      addItem(hmS2I, hmI2S, "ansh5",1);

      System.out.println("string-to-int:");
         Set<String> stStrKeys = hmS2I.keySet();
         Iterator<String> itrs = stStrKeys.iterator();
         while(itrs.hasNext())  {
            String s = itrs.next();
            System.out.println(s + ": " + hmS2I.get(s));
         }
         System.out.println();

      System.out.println("int-to-string:");
         Set<Integer> stIntKeys = hmI2S.keySet();
         Iterator<Integer> itri = stIntKeys.iterator();
         while(itri.hasNext())  {
            Integer I = itri.next();
            System.out.println(I + ": " + Arrays.toString(hmI2S.get(I).toArray()));
         }
         System.out.println();

   }
   private static final void addItem(HashMap<String,Integer> hm_strToInt, HashMap<Integer,List<String>> hm_intToStr, String s_text, int i_num)  {
      hm_strToInt.put(s_text, i_num);

      if(hm_intToStr.containsKey(i_num))  {
         hm_intToStr.get(i_num).add(s_text);

      }  else  {
         ArrayList<String> als = new ArrayList<String>(5);
         als.add(s_text);
         hm_intToStr.put(i_num, als);
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java MapAndReverseMapXmpl
string-to-int:
ansh3: 3
ansh2: 2
ansh5: 1
ansh: 1
ansh4: 1

int-to-string:
1: [ansh, ansh4, ansh5]
2: [ansh2]
3: [ansh3]
```